# Avoid overlapping labels in transition diagram using R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am looking for suggestions and advices for generating transition diagrams for finite state machine. I hope to place two graphs on each page and export the results to a PDF file. The issue is, however I tune the parameters in `plotmat` function, I always get overlapping labels in the output.

I wonder:

1. Is anyone familiar with `diagram` package? Does it support layout options (e.g., force atlas)?
2. Are there any better options for generating similar transition matrix in R? (I know we can do tons of things in python... but I have to deal with R for the moment)

Here's a toy example:

```
pdf('toy_ex.pdf')
par(mfrow = c(2,1))
mat1 <- matrix(c(0,0,0.5,0.25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0.5,0,0,0,0.5,0,0.5,1,0,0,0,0.25,0), nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)
plotmat(mat1, relsize = 0.6, shadow.size = 0, cex.txt = 0.6, box.cex = 0.6, self.cex = 0.6, self.shiftx = -0.1, arr.type = 'simple', arr.length = 0.2, name = c('None', 'Raccoon', 'Giraffe','Lion','Oyster'), main = 'Transition', cex.main = 1)
mat2 <- mat1
plotmat(mat2, relsize = 0.6, shadow.size = 0, cex.txt = 0.6, box.cex = 0.6, self.cex = 0.6, self.shiftx = -0.1, arr.type = 'simple', arr.length = 0.2, name = c('None', 'Raccoon', 'Giraffe','Lion','Oyster'), main = 'Transition', cex.main = 1)
dev.off()
```

This is what the output looks like. I know it's messy...

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try using `igraph`

example

```
library(igraph)
rownames(mat1) = c('None', 'Raccoon', 'Giraffe','Lion','Oyster')
colnames(mat1) = c('None', 'Raccoon', 'Giraffe','Lion','Oyster')
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mat1, weighted = "prob")
plot(g, 
     edge.label = E(g)$prob,
     edge.arrow.size = 1,
     edge.label.cex = 1.5,
     edge.curved = TRUE,
     layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold,
     vertex.size = 45,
     vertex.color="lightblue",
     vertex.frame.color= "black",
     vertex.label.color = "black",
     vertex.label.family = "sans",
     edge.width = 1.5,  
     edge.color="grey50", 
     edge.label.dist = 0)
```

[image]

I just realized all the directions are reversed - quick fix is to use `t(mat1)` since `plotmat` uses `(rows=to, cols=from)` while `igraph` uses `(rows=from, cols=to)`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colors so it looks better:

```
require(diagram)

plotmat(mat2, relsize = 0.6, shadow.size = 0, cex.txt = 0.6, box.cex = 0.6,
  self.cex = 0.6, self.shiftx = -0.1, arr.type = 'simple', arr.length = 0.2, 
  name = c('None', 'Raccoon', 'Giraffe','Lion','Oyster'), main = 'Transition', cex.main = 1,
  txt.col="black",box.col="lightblue", lcol="grey")
```